# Mongo C# driver try reconnect on connection failure

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a common way to recover from a connection error in MongoDB with the C# driver?
Currently, my Windows service shuts down if MongoDB is turned off. I currently have my app structured like this at the start of my Windows service:

```
//Set up connections for Mongo
var con = new MongoConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoDB"].ConnectionString);
var client = new MongoClient(con.ToString());
var server = client.GetServer();
var db = server.GetDatabase(con.DatabaseName);
```

I then inject the db object into my repositories.

I'm trying to find something like an event handler or a condition I could listen to in my whole application to prevent from crashing the entire service should mongo go down for some reason.

Comment: So if MongoDB is turned down, and db throws an exception, which you don't catch, and finally bring down the service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by the [driver document](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/), the `MongoClient` is added to manage Replica Set stuff, which earlier or later you will need. To avoid mass code refactoring then, you need to make better use of it now.
The `MongoClient`, which is thread-safe, have implemented the failover logic among replica set nodes already. It's supposed to be singleton along with your application domain. Thus you can inject the MongoClient, other than db (which is not even thread safe).

So always retry the `GetServer()` and `GetDatabase()` from `MongoClient`, and try/catch the exceptions produced by them would finally give you the available db object when MongoDB is online again.
The point is, MongoDB will not notify the clients about its online, so there's no such event to notify you, either. You'll have to keep trying in your client side until it's ok. And to avoid the exceptions to bring down your service, you'll have to catch them.

**EDIT**: I am wrong about the thread-safety according to the [document](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#thread-safety). However, it doesn't change the fact you shouldn't store MongoDatabase for future migration to replica set.

Comment: Based on your suggestions what I should be doing is instead inject a singleton MongoClient to my repositories and have the repositories in charge of getting the server and database so that I can catch any errors connecting to prevent my service from crashing. I agree that I need replication sooner to better handle this situation.

Comment: Things may have changed a bit since the original question.   It appears that MongoClient is thread safe and a singleton is a recommended practice.   See http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/connecting/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to yaoxing answer, wanted to do show code piece to solve this issue.

```
var client = new MongoClient(connString);
var server = client.GetServer();

while (server.State == MongoServerState.Disconnected)
{
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   try
   { 
      server.Reconnect(); 
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   { 
      Debug.WriteLine("Failed to connect mongodb {0} Attempt Count: {1}",
                       ex, server.ConnectionAttempt); 
   }
}
```